# Physics package manual resize of \ket and \bra

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, physics

I am trying to manually force big size for a `\ket` using the physics package, I am trying something along the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
$\ket\Big{a}$
\end{document}
```

I am trying this based on the physics package documentation where `\qty\Big{}` should results in big brackets/braces. However, my example above generates the following compilation error:

```
! Argument of \bBigg@ has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.4 $\ket\Big
             {a}$
```

On the other hand, when I try `$\abs\Big{a}$` it works just fine ...
Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I don't think the `physics` package provides for that. On the other hand the definition of `\ket` is quite peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly code for an ugly syntax. `;-)`

Here are replacements for `\bra` and `\ket` that allow for specifying an explicit size for the delimiters.

I made no provision for things like

```
\BRA\big{x}\KET\Bigg{y}
```

and just the first size command is considered. If you like them, change

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\BRA}
```

into

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bra}
```

and similarly for `\NewDocumentCommand{\KET}`. Also change

```
  \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \KET
```

into

```
  \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \ket
```

and you'll have a full replacement.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_braket_explicit_tl
\tl_new:N \l_braket_bra_tl
\bool_new:N \l_braket_resize_bool

\NewDocumentCommand{\BRA}{ l m }
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_braket_resize_bool
  \str_case:xnF { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
   {
    { } { \tl_clear:N \l_braket_explicit_tl }
    { * } { \bool_set_false:N \l_braket_resize_bool }
   }
   {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_braket_resize_bool
    \tl_set:Nn \l_braket_explicit_tl { #1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_braket_bra_tl { #2 }
  \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \KET
   {
    \BRAKETfinish
   }
   {
    \braket_bra:
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { x }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \braket_bra:
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_braket_resize_bool
   {
    \left\langle\l_braket_bra_tl\right\rvert
   }
   {
    \mathinner
     {
      \mathopen{\l_braket_explicit_tl\langle}
      \l_braket_bra_tl
      \mathclose{\l_braket_explicit_tl\rvert}
     }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\BRAKETfinish}{ l m }
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \l_braket_resize_bool
   {
    \left\langle\l_braket_bra_tl\middle|#2\right\rangle
   }
   {
    \mathinner
     {
      \mathopen{\l_braket_explicit_tl\langle}
      \l_braket_bra_tl\l_braket_explicit_tl|#2
      \mathclose{\l_braket_explicit_tl\rangle}
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\KET}{ l m }
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_braket_resize_bool
  \str_case:xnF { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
   {
    { } { }
    { * } { \bool_set_false:N \l_braket_resize_bool }
   }
   {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_braket_resize_bool
    \tl_set:Nn \l_braket_explicit_tl { #1 }
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_braket_resize_bool
   {
    \left\lvert#2\right\rangle
   }
   {
    \mathinner
     {
      \mathopen{\l_braket_explicit_tl|}
      #2
      \mathclose{\l_braket_explicit_tl\rvert}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a+\bra{x}+b$ $a+\bra*{x}+b$ $a+\bra{x}\ket{y}+b$ $a+\bra*{x}\ket*{y}+b$ $a+\ket{y}+b$

$a+\BRA{x}+b$ $a+\BRA*{x}+b$ $a+\BRA{x}\KET{y}+b$ $a+\BRA*{x}\KET*{y}+b$ $a+\KET{y}+b$

$\BRA\big{x}$ $\BRA\Big{x}\KET{y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can surely notice that the original `\bra*{x}` command has wrong spacing, which is fixed in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You could enlist the help of the [mathtools](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package and redefine `\ket` to make it recognize an optional explicit sizing directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics}
\let\ket\relax % undefine \ket

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}  % "\ket" autosizes the fences
$\ket{a} \quad \ket[\big]{a} \quad \ket[\Big]{a} \quad \ket*{\dfrac{a}{b}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will break the purpose of the physics package. For example, with the physics package, I can say `\bra{a}\ket{b}` and it will automatically contract to `<a|b>`....